# Tweaking of Section style in amsbook class

Tags: sectioning, amsbook

I wanted to have less spacing before and after the section title in the `amsbook` class. Therefore, I changed the definition of the macro `\@startsection` as indicated in the documentation. Unfortunately, now my section titles are not centered anymore but flushleft, and I also lost the property of not being on the last line of a page. What happened and how can I recover these two properties, still changing the `\vskip` before and after ?

PS: I do not want to use any package for that.

Here is my MWE

```
\documentclass[oneside]{amsbook} 
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection{section{1}\z@{.3\linespacing\@plus\linespacing}{.0\linespacing}{\centering\normalfont\bfseries}}
\makeatother 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document} 
\section{StackExchange} 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fifth argument to `\@startsection` should be positive:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{amsbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section{%
  \@startsection{section}{1}
    \z@
    {.3\linespacing\@plus\linespacing}
    {1sp}
    {\normalfont\bfseries\centering}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{StackExchange}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

The length 1sp is the least possible positive length (much less than the wavelength of visible light).

[image]

Comment: clear as visible light !

Comment: @brunoh This has historic reasons. In order to save memory and parameters, the arguments to `\@startsection` are overloaded. If the fifth argument is not positive, the section title is typeset “in line”. Similarly, a negative value of the fourth argument inhibits the indentation of the next paragraph.

Comment: +1 brighter than visible light !  thanks for the explanation.